# db.sqlite3 file not getting read or write in django on ubuntu server but working fine on localhost

Tags: ubuntu, server, django-templates

**Error**

[image]

**Permissions**

[image]

***Note***
one thing i can tell that, same model worked fine on ubuntu server 20.04 but not working on 22.04 . Also in directory of 20.04, all db file when created, having default access for www-data for both group and user, but on 22.04 only group having www-data access and users having root access.

I have tried all type of permission but still not working. Can anyone please me with it?. I will be very thankful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It was migration problem. I needed to update the server **using sudo apt-get update**. needed to convert weights' path to full path first. (because every time server were loading old migrations).